# Python UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 670: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, ipython, python-unicode

I looked in Stackoverflow but every Topic I looked up for provide unfortunately not the solution for this Problem. so I thought when I add "encoding = 'utf-8'" or latin etc in the pd.read_csv it should fix the problem but it wont. So why does this error occur?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("https://opendata.ecdc.europa.eu/covid19/casedistribution/csv", index_col = 0, parse_dates = True, encoding="ISO-8859-1")


df["cases"] = pd.to_numeric(df["cases"])
df["deaths"] = pd.to_numeric(df["deaths"])
df["deaths by cases"] = df["deaths"].divide(df["cases"])
df = df.replace(np.inf, 0)
df = df.replace(np.nan,0)

df.rename(columns={"Cumulative_number_for_14_days_of_COVID-19_cases_per_100000" : "cum per 100000"}, 
           inplace=True)


d = {1:"Januar", 2:"Februar", 3:"März", 4:"April", 5:"Mai", 6:"Juni", 7:"Juli"}
df.month = df.month.map(d)

df= df.pivot_table(values = "deaths by cases", index = ["month", "countriesAndTerritories"])
df = df.reset_index()

print(df)
data = [go.Scatter(
    x = df["month"],
    y = df["deaths by cases"],
    mode = 'markers',
        )]
layout = go.Layout(
    title = 'Random Data Scatterplot', 
    xaxis = dict(title = 'Some random x-values'), 
    yaxis = dict(title = 'Some random y-values'), 
    hovermode ='closest' 
    )
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
pyo.plot(fig, filename='scatter3.html')
```

Error Traceback of the Code:

runfile('C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Busines Intelligence Learning/Python Dash/Plotly-Dashboards-mit-Dash-v2/Plotly-Dashboards-mit-Dash-v2/1-02-Streudiagramm/scatter3.py', wdir='C:/Users/Asus/Desktop/Busines Intelligence Learning/Python Dash/Plotly-Dashboards-mit-Dash-v2/Plotly-Dashboards-mit-Dash-v2/1-02-Streudiagramm')
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
self.showtraceback(running_compiled_code=True)

File "C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2026, in showtraceback
self.showsyntaxerror(filename, running_compiled_code)

File "C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2088, in showsyntaxerror
stb = self.SyntaxTB.structured_traceback(etype, value, elist)

File "C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py", line 1420, in structured_traceback
newtext = linecache.getline(value.filename, value.lineno)

File "C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 16, in getline
lines = getlines(filename, module_globals)

File "C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 47, in getlines
return updatecache(filename, module_globals)

File "C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\linecache.py", line 137, in updatecache
lines = fp.readlines()

File "C:\Users\Asus\Anaconda3\lib\codecs.py", line 322, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 666: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Code, as is, doesn't compile.
Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I thought he cant compile because of this error im getting which I stated in the Topic. if so he can compile until the print function (print(df)). after That the Problem occurs

Comment: If the error occurs in the print call, then the code after the print call can be deleted.

Comment: If you change the month names to their English equivalents, does the error still occur?

Comment: Thanks! it worked. apparently I think the "ä" made the problem now with the English equivalents it worked.

Comment: Hmmm.  I'm guessing that your system's default  encoding is not UTF-8, and this is confusing iPython somehow.  Unfortunately I don't have a suitable environment to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Setting the `PYTHONIOENCODING` environment variable to `UTF-8` _might_ be a better workaraound; there are a few answers that suggest `sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')` but this is not a recommended solution.